# Rails 3.0.7 caching font issue

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fonts

I have an application running on Rails 3.0.7, thin 1.2.11, and nginx 0.7.65. The main index page for my website has a link to my "résumé", accents included. The page is rendering fine, however, after the initial view, once the page is cached, the text is displayed as "RÃ©sumÃ©". I have absolutely no idea why this is happening, what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Was solved by adding this in `head`:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: That did the trick, any idea to what was causing the weird text?

Comment: I guess the browser isn't sure about utf8 content, that was my first idea when I faced that and I didn't search more 'cause it was fixed

Comment: In [UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), any character outside the basic ascii character range is encoded as multiple bytes. In the case of 'é', it is encoded as the two bytes `c3 a9` (in hex). If this page is then read in the [latin1 or 8859-1 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) which is a single byte encoding and the default for HTML, that sequence is interpreted as two separate characters `c3` which is 'Ã' and `a9`, which is '©', hence you see 'Ã©'. The meta tag you add specifies to always treat the page as utf8.

Comment: Why the page was being interpreted in one encoding first, and then a different encoding later I don't know, but hopefully my above comment explains a bit about what's going on. (I somehow find myself knowing more about character encoding issues than I really want :-) ).