# incompatible character encodings with memcached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, memcached, ruby-1.9.2

I'm getting a rails error because it's expecting UTF-8, memcached is converting my string into ASCII-8BIT.  I'm caching currency data including the symbol to prevent unnecessary hits to the DB.

My method here:

```
  def self.find_symbol(currency)
    Rails.cache.fetch(currency, :expires_in => 1.week) { Currency.find_by_code(currency).symbol }
  end
```

The part being cached is in UTF-8.

```
Currency.find_by_code(currency).symbol
```

However when it comes out of the method is in ASCII-8BIT and looks like "\xE2\x82\xAC"

I'm unsure how memcache handles strings, if I should/can force it so save the string as UTF, (no idea why it converts it) or force it back to UTF when I pull it out?

Comment: did you set the utf type in your head section?

Comment: the head section where?  I'm assuming you're not talking about the head of the HTML/the doctype.  This is a ruby 1.9 error, worked fine in 1.8.7

Comment: I do speak about the html part: I had encoding problems with cache pages and adding utf in the head solved it.

Comment: seems to be this: https://github.com/mperham/dalli/issues/78?authenticity_token=37e6064fd904ad79374cbb3297ce62f2ca575292

Comment: ok :) thougt was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735793/rails-3-0-7-caching-font-issue/5735838#comment-6561761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgraded to rails 3.0.7 and that fixed it.

As of Dalli 1.0.3 and Rails 3.0.7 it now works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure memcached just handles the key values as straight bytes and isn't aware of character sets.

This would suggest that this is some kind of rails issue.